# Finding Total Tenure of Employees with Multiple Stints in the Company

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions

I have a dataset that goes back to Jan 1, 2018 for employee history including hire and termination data.  Prior to 2018 there is no history, however I do have original hire dates and continuous services dates prior.  For example, I might have a datapoint that employee 123456 was termed on 2/15/2018 and had a hire date on 1/9/2014.  But anyone who was termed prior to 2018 and never rehired, there is no data.

The logic I implemented was as follows:

1. Always consider the earliest of the original hire date or continuous service date as the date of first hire.
2. If earliest hire was before 2018 and the employee's first action in the database was to be rehired, then assume 1/1/2018 was the first termination date.
3. Add the hire and term activity after 1/1/2018
4. Add up all the days employed from all their stints

Here is some example data from one employee:

| Employee ID | Employee Original Hire Date | Employment Status | Employee Termination Date | Employee Trend Date | Employee Action | Service Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 2015-03-31 | Leave | 2019-06-24 | 2018-01-01 | Data Changes | 2020-02-24 |
| 123456 | 2015-03-31 | Active | 2019-06-24 | 2018-02-26 | Leave | 2020-02-24 |
| 123456 | 2015-03-31 | Active | 2019-06-24 | 2019-02-04 | Leave | 2020-02-24 |
| 123456 | 2015-03-31 | Term | 2019-06-24 | 2019-06-24 | Voluntary | 2020-02-24 |
| 123456 | 2015-03-31 | Active | 2022-06-17 | 2020-02-24 | Rehire Employee | - |
| 123456 | 2015-03-31 | Active | 2022-06-17 | 2020-02-26 | Transfer | 2020-02-24 |
| 123456 | 2015-03-31 | Leave | 2022-06-17 | 2020-11-23 | Leave | 2020-02-24 |
| 123456 | 2015-03-31 | Active | 2022-06-17 | 2021-02-22 | Leave | 2020-02-24 |
| 123456 | 2015-03-31 | Leave | 2022-06-17 | 2021-11-12 | Leave | 2020-02-24 |
| 123456 | 2015-03-31 | Leave | 2022-06-17 | 2021-12-27 | Data Changes | 2020-02-24 |
| 123456 | 2015-03-31 | Active | 2022-06-17 | 2022-02-13 | Leave | 2020-02-24 |
| 123456 | 2015-03-31 | Term | 2022-06-17 | 2022-06-17 | Involuntary | 2020-02-24 |

Note: Voluntary and Involuntary both refer to being Termed

And here is an intermediate step of my function:

| stint | Hired | Termed | stintlength |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2015-03-31 | 2019-06-24 | 1546 |
| 2 | 2020-02-24 | 2022-06-17 | 844 |

The final output simply sums the stintlength and return it.  So the function seems to work.

The problem is it is slow.  Super slow.  About 3,500 rows a minute slow.  I'd like to improve the speed by 10x.

Here is the code:

```
DECLARE @eeid int
DECLARE @lastupdated date
DECLARE @firsttrend date
DECLARE @firststatus nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @firstservicedate date
DECLARE @activejan2018 bit
DECLARE @mintermdate date
DECLARE @firsttermdate date
DECLARE @return int

SET @eeid = 143914
SET @lastupdated = (SELECT MAX(lastupdated) FROM cleandata.employeefullhistory2)
SET @firsttrend = (SELECT MIN(Employee_Trend_Date) FROM cleandata.employeefullhistory2 WHERE Employee_ID = @eeid)
SET @mintermdate = (SELECT MIN(Employee_Trend_Date) FROM cleandata.employeefullhistory2 WHERE Employee_ID = @eeid AND (Employee_Action = 'Voluntary' OR Employee_Action = 'Involuntary'))
SET @firstservicedate = (SELECT IIF(MIN(Employee_Original_Hire_Date)>MIN(Service_Date),MIN(Service_Date),MIN(Employee_Original_Hire_Date)) FROM cleandata.employeefullhistory2 WHERE Employee_ID = @eeid)
SET @firststatus =(SELECT TOP 1 Employee_Action FROM cleandata.employeefullhistory2 WHERE Employee_ID = @eeid AND Employee_Trend_Date = @firsttrend)
SET @activejan2018 = CASE WHEN @firstservicedate <= '2018-01-01' AND NOT (@firststatus = 'Rehire Employee' OR @firststatus = 'Hire Employee') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
SET @firsttermdate = CASE WHEN @firstservicedate <= '2018-01-01' AND @activejan2018 = 0 THEN '2018-01-01' ELSE @mintermdate END




SET @return = (SELECT SUM(stintlength) FROM (

    SELECT
        stint
        ,[Hired]
        ,CASE WHEN [Termed] IS NULL THEN @lastupdated ELSE [Termed] END Termed
        ,DATEDIFF(DAY,[Hired],CASE WHEN [Termed] IS NULL THEN @lastupdated ELSE [Termed] END) stintlength
    FROM(
        SELECT 
            t.trenddate
            ,t.status
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.status ORDER BY t.trenddate asc) stint
        FROM(
            SELECT @firstservicedate trenddate, 'Hired' status
            UNION
            SELECT @firsttermdate trenddate, 'Termed'
            UNION
            SELECT 
                Employee_Trend_Date
                ,CASE WHEN Employee_Action = 'Voluntary' OR Employee_Action = 'Involuntary' THEN 'Termed' ELSE 'Hired' END
            FROM cleandata.employeefullhistory2
            WHERE Employee_ID = @eeid AND (Employee_Action = 'Voluntary' OR Employee_Action = 'Involuntary' OR Employee_Action = 'Hire Employee' OR Employee_Action = 'Rehire Employee')
        )t 
    )t
    PIVOT (
        MIN(trenddate)
        FOR status IN ([Hired],[Termed])
    ) pt
)t)

SELECT @return
```

Comment: If you want performance assistance you need to include the execution plan using Paste The Plan. Also table definitions and indexes. The query itself provides minimal information as to how it performs because who knows how SQL Server solves the problem under the hood - hence the execution plan.

Comment: I would add all of your variables as new columns in a query: lastupdated, firsttrend, minterdate, etc. Hopefully SQL Server lets you do that with a window function with OVER() PARTITION_BY EmployeeID.  Then you use CTEs or Subqueries to apply the rest of the vars with CASE or IIF statements. I think that'll improve performance dramatically.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've probably made it much more complicated than it should be.

Rather than doing a PIVOT etc, you can simply 'group' the relevant rows and get max/min dates - and then do any modifications to those to account for results prior to 1/1/2018. Then (as you have), simply sum the stint_lengths.

I have a running example in [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/b7BTayf_) - note though that I have called the table `#employeefullhistory2`.

I would suggest the first step (which is used in the later code) is to just pull out the relevant data e.g.,

```
SELECT  Employee_ID, 
        Employee_Original_Hire_Date, 
        Employee_Termination_Date, 
        MIN(Employee_Trend_Date) AS First_Trend_Date, 
        MAX(Employee_Trend_Date) AS Last_Trend_Date
FROM    #employeefullhistory2
GROUP BY Employee_ID, 
        Employee_Original_Hire_Date, 
        Employee_Termination_Date;
```

The above uses a simply GROUP BY and MIN/MAX calculations, to work out key dates. Results as below.

```
Employee_ID Employee_Original_Hire_Date Employee_Termination_Date   First_Trend_Date    Last_Trend_Date
123456      2015-03-31                  2019-06-24                  2018-01-01          2019-06-24
123456      2015-03-31                  2022-06-17                  2020-02-24          2022-06-17
```

Once you have this, it's easy enough to calculate the relevant Stint_Lengths (see the db<>fiddle linked above for that) and then take the total.

The full/final SQL query is below.

```
WITH EmpDates AS
        (SELECT Employee_ID, 
                Employee_Original_Hire_Date, 
                Employee_Termination_Date, 
                MIN(Employee_Trend_Date) AS First_Trend_Date, 
                MAX(Employee_Trend_Date) AS Last_Trend_Date
        FROM    #employeefullhistory2
        GROUP BY Employee_ID, 
                Employee_Original_Hire_Date, 
                Employee_Termination_Date
        ),
    EmpStints AS
        (SELECT *,
                DATEDIFF(day, 
                        CASE WHEN First_Trend_Date = '2018-01-01' 
                            THEN Employee_Original_Hire_Date 
                            ELSE First_Trend_Date END, 
                        ISNULL(Employee_Termination_Date, Last_Trend_Date)
                    ) AS Stint_Length
        FROM    EmpDates
        )
    SELECT  Employee_ID, SUM(Stint_Length) AS Total_Stint_Length
    FROM    EmpStints
    GROUP BY Employee_ID;
```

The results are as follows

```
Employee_ID Total_Stint_Length
123456      2390
```

I think the simplicity of the above approach will make it run much faster. If you need the results for a single employee (e.g., you pass a specific Employee_ID) then it's worthwhile on the original data set to have an index on Employee_ID.

Note: For current employees, I have used the last Trend Date to mimic their termination date for the purposes of stint length calculation (the `ISNULL(Employee_Termination_Date, Last_Trend_Date)` function). This means that someone who has been hired for (say) 2 years and is still employed (e.g., no termination date) will have a ~700 days value for the current stint. Feel free to modify the approach as needed.

Comment: Thank you so much for this.  Ultimately this did not solve my issue.  I was unable to fully recreate the business logic I used with that solution (I came very close, but one part held me up).  But you did inspire a ton of tinkering and I tried various parts of your solution to make it more efficient.  Ultimately what worked: I removed one line of code from the function.  SET @lastupdated = (SELECT MAX(lastupdated) FROM cleandata.employeefullhistory2)  I pulled that out from the function and instead passed it to the function as a parameter. Not sure why that one was worse than the others.

Comment: Calling the function 46,000 times went from 12 minutes to 4 seconds!